# Oracle 10+ DB - Hibernate interpreting all Number(1) fields as false

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to implement a filtering method with a set of category records as part of a module upgrade.  To do so, I added

```
IS_ENABLED NUMBER(1,0)
```

to the CATEGORY table and each row has either a 0 or 1 for false or true, respectively.

```
ID  NAME                DISPLAY IS_ENABLED
                        ORDER
12  Direct Mail         6       1
1   Annual reports      null    0
2   Books               1       1
3   Brochures           2       1 
4   Calendars           null    0
5   Catalogs            3       1
6   Digital Print       5       1
7   Magazines 
    (sheetfed)          8       1
8   Magazines (web)     9       1
9   Printer's own 
    promotions          10      1
10  General print       7       1
```

I also modified the Hibernate config file by adding

```
<property name="enabled" type = "boolean">
    <column name="IS_ENABLED" />
</property>
```

and adding the corresponding boolean field with getters and setters in the POJO model.  The model includes a `toString()` method which includes the name, order and enabled status of the row record.

```
public class Category implements java.io.Serializable {

private long id;
private String name;
private Short displayOrder;
private boolean enabled;

    //getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString(){
    return this.id + "\t" + this.name + "\t" + this.enabled + "\t" + this.displayOrder + "\n";
}
```

My issue is the toString() is printing out

```
Current category: 2    Books         false  1
Current category: 3    Brochures     false  2
Current category: 5    Catalogs      false  3
Current category: 6    Digital Print false  5
Current category: 12   Direct Mail   false  6
Current category: 10   General print false  7
Current category: 7    Magazines 
                       (sheetfed)    false  8
Current category: 8    Magazines 
                       (web)         false  9
Current category: 9    Printer's own 
                       promotions    false  10
Current category: 1    Annual 
                       reports       false  null
Current category: 4    Calendars     false  null
```

As you can see, everything is coming through false, which is not what it should be.  What needs to be done to have the instance `enabled` property reflect the database value?

Comment: Been a while since I did mapping, but shouldn't the type be `numeric_boolean`?

Comment: Adding `numeric_boolean` as type had no effect.

Comment: numeric_boolean is what you want.  If that's not working, double-check in your database that IS_ENABLED still has correct values - Hibernate may have "helpfully" updated everything to 0 for you at some point.

Comment: Database has remained unchanged, and values coming through are still false for all values. At this point, I'm considering implementing an enum with ids to be filtered out. Not best practice, I know, but after a day and a half on this one issue, I'll take anything that works.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try using field-level access: <property name="enabled" type="numeric_boolean" access="field">